# updating DOM through ajax call back with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, dynamic, scope

I'm working on a calendar that will allow users to store events on a given date. when I update the calendar each new month I create new nodes and assign them an id so I will be able to append something to them later like so:

```
 var i = 1;
  for(var w in weeks){
    var days = weeks[w].getDates();
    // days contains normal JavaScript Date objects.

   // alert("Week starting on "+days[0]);
    var which_week = "week"+i;
    i++;
    for(var d in days){     
      console.log(days[d].toISOString());
      var tr = document.getElementById(which_week);
      if(days[d].getMonth()==month){

        var newDay = document.createElement("div");
        newDay.appendChild(document.createTextNode(days[d].getDate()));
        //alert(newDay.data);
        newDay.setAttribute("id", newDay.lastChild.data);
        $(tr).append('<td><a class="linky" href="#">'+newDay.lastChild.data+'</a></td>');
      }
      else{
        $(tr).append('<td class="disabledCell"><a class="linky disabledLink" href="#">'+days[d].getDate()+'</a></td>');
      }
    }
  }
  getEvents();
}
```

I modify the nodes:

```
function ajaxEventCallback(event){
  var data = event.target.responseText;
  data = JSON.parse(event.target.responseText);
  for  (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
    //alert("event: " + data[i].title);
    //
    var dayOfEvent= data[i].day;
    document.getElementById(dayOfEvent).appendChild(data[i].title);

}
```

I get a "cannot read property append child of null" error on the last line of code. I think it's a scoping issue but I don't know where to begin solving it.

Comment: yea that's why I thought it was a scoping issue because I create elements with all possible dayOfEvent id's in the first block of code

Comment: On this line `newDay.appendChild(document.createTextNode(days[d].getDate()));` you are appending to `newDay` plain text meaning that you cannot access the last one from `newDay.lastChild` since it is not wrapped inside a tag

Comment: I would change this `newDay.appendChild(document.createTextNode(days[d].getDate()));` to something like `newDay.appendChild("<span>" + days[d].getDate() + "</span>");` or whichever tag you like and change this `newDay.lastChild.data` to this `newDay.lastChild.innerHTML` and everything should work as expected.

Comment: I made those changes but the error is still the same. This might not be clear in my first post but the first and second blocks of code are two separate functions so I was thinking that the elements created in the first function don't exist outside of that function which is why I'm getting null errors.

Comment: Yes, you are right. `newDay` exists only in the first function, and the reason you are getting this error is because `newDay` is never appended onto the body and therefore cannot be accessed via `document.getElementById()`

Comment: And since the variable `newDay` is created inside the `for..in` loop, it is deleted every time the `for` loop goes to the next object.

Comment: huh well do you know if its possible to instantiate the elements inside the for loop and declare them global?

Comment: I think it would be a pain to use DOM objects and store them at a global scope, and since you never add them to the DOM anyway, there is kind of no point. Instead I would use arrays, i.e. an array of weeks at the global scope and each week would contain an array of days. Using this method you could add a week to the week array each time in the week `for` loop and for each day in the day `for` loop you would add a day to the appropriate week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the global scope:

```
var allWeeks = [];
```

In the first function:

```
var i = 1;
for(var w in weeks){
    var days = weeks[w].getDates();
    // days contains normal JavaScript Date objects.

    // week object used to store the days until it is added to the array
    var week = [];

    var which_week = "week"+i;
    i++;
    for(var d in days){     
        console.log(days[d].toISOString());
        var tr = document.getElementById(which_week);
        if(days[d].getMonth()==month){

            // add the day to the temporary week object
            week.push(days[d].getDate());

            $(tr).append('<td><a class="linky" href="#">' + days[d].getDate() + '</a></td>');
        }
        else{
            $(tr).append('<td class="disabledCell"><a class="linky disabledLink" href="#">'+days[d].getDate()+'</a></td>');
        }

    }

    // add the temporary week array to the array of weeks
    allWeeks.push(week);
}
```

In the ajax event:

```
function ajaxEventCallback(event){
    var data = event.target.responseText;
    data = JSON.parse(event.target.responseText);

    for  (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var dayOfEvent = data[i].day;
        // Here you add the event to the appropriate day in the array
    }
}
```